# easy to implement calendar pod? obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I'm looking for a easy to implement calendar pod in obj c. I've seen fscalendar and calendarlib. Does anyone know which is easier to implement or know an easier pod?

I want a calendar that display certain events that I supply it.

Answer (score 0):

Go for JTCalender. [Here it is.](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar)